# I have my div set to bottom:0;, and the bottom goes to the bottom, but the content does not move

Tags: javascript, html, css

[My blog](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com)'s popup posts are set to bottom:0; but the content in the div won't budge while the div actually is at the bottom... Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using a monitor of 1280 x 800, and it seems that the content of each post is in the middle (half-way down) of the screen. Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: Well it's at the top for me but its just monitor size. The content just won't go down even though the div is bottom:0; :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the top position in javascript, which is overriding your css value. Look at line 173:

```
 info.css({
                        top: -90,
                        left: -33,
                        display: 'block'
```

Perhaps you should try setting the bottom instead?

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out! Sometimes I just stay up too late. It changed, but I set bottom: 0, and it didn't go to the bottom, I think it just sort of stayed at the top but you can see all the content.